# python pandas: pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like so:

```
Name   | ID | Contact_method | Contact
sarah    1   house            h1
sarah    1   mobile           m1
sarah    1   email            sarah@mail
bob      2   house            h2
bob      2   mobile           m2
bob      2   email            bob@mail
jones    3   house            h3
jones    3   mobile           m3
jones    3   email            jones@mail
jones    4   house            h4
jones    4   mobile           m4
jones    4   email            jones2@mail
```

And I want it like so:

```
Name  | ID | house | mobile | email
sarah   1    h1      m1       sarah@mail
bob     2    h2      m2       bob@mail
jones   3    h3      m3       jones@mail
jones   4    h4      m4       jones2@mail
```

I can already do this, but only through a very expensive `pd.concat` operation iterated over all the unique IDs. Is there a simple way to do this? I've also tinkered with `pivot()` and `transpose()`. Note that the duplicate name is there so that I can't rely on uniqueness of column values to, say, do a `join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the index with all columns except `'Contact_method'`, then `unstack`

```
df.set_index(
    ['Name', 'ID', 'Contact_method']
)['Contact'].unstack().rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()

    Name  ID        email house mobile
0    bob   2     bob@mail    h2     m2
1  jones   3   jones@mail    h3     m3
2  jones   4  jones2@mail    h4     m4
3  sarah   1   sarah@mail    h1     m1
```

Comment: I have a desk to sit at in my new temporary place while we continue to look for houses.  I am set up to work remotely for the time being.  I'll be commuting back to Seattle twice a month.  And soon I have to go back to get rid of all my stuff at old place.  Still busy, but I've enjoyed having some time to answer questions.  I hope your doing well!  @jezrael

Comment: @jezrael yeah, I made a big push for legendary then I felt I could calm down a bit.  You're almost top pandas all time.  My next SO goal will be to get past DSM and Jeff on that list.  I've never been very motivated by rep itself.  I've given a lot away.  I'll get 100k eventually.. I do want a t-shirt.  You'll have to let me know if they give you anything.

Comment: I'd want to participate in http://stats.stackexchange.com/ and http://quant.stackexchange.com/.  However, I'd rather pick some other tags to get gold in.  Like, I want my numpy badge, I've neglected my machine learning stuff. I want to get a gold badge in tensorflow (though I still have a lot to learn)

Comment: you want to start participating in meta?  I think you'd be a good mod!  You think about running for a position? @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

One way is to build a contact dictionary (of dictionaries) based on ID, 'manualy'. Not sure if it is more efficient though.

```
people = dict()
for index, row in pd.iterrows():
    ID = row['ID']
    if ID not in people:
        people[ID] = {'ID': ID, 'Name': row['Name']}
    people[ID][row['Contact_method']] = row['Contact']

print pandas.DataFrame(people).transpose()
```

And output is:

```
  ID   Name        email house mobile
1  1  sarah   sarah@mail    h1     m1
2  2    bob     bob@mail    h2     m2
3  3  jones   jones@mail    h3     m3
4  4  jones  jones2@mail    h4     m4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [piRSquared's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42846893/2901002) is very nice, but if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

```
print (df)
     Name  ID Contact_method      Contact
0   sarah   1          house           h1
1   sarah   1         mobile           m1
2   sarah   1          email   sarah@mail
3     bob   2          house           h2
4     bob   2         mobile           m2
5     bob   2          email     bob@mail
6   jones   3          house           h3
7   jones   3         mobile           m3
8   jones   3          email   jones@mail <-for same Name,ID and Contact_method get duplicate
9   jones   3          email     joe@mail <-for same Name,ID and Contact_method get duplicate
10  jones   4          house           h4
11  jones   4         mobile           m4
12  jones   4          email  jones2@mail
```

use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) or `groubpy` with aggregating `join`:

```
cols = ['Name','ID','house','mobile','email']
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['ID','Name'],
                     columns='Contact_method', 
                     values='Contact', 
                     aggfunc=','.join)
        .rename_axis(None, 1)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (df1)
    Name  ID house mobile                email
0  sarah   1    h1     m1           sarah@mail
1    bob   2    h2     m2             bob@mail
2  jones   3    h3     m3  jones@mail,joe@mail <- join duplicates
3  jones   4    h4     m4          jones2@mail

df1 = df.groupby(['Name', 'ID', 'Contact_method'])['Contact']
        .apply(','.join)
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis(None, 1)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (df1)
    Name  ID house mobile                email
0  sarah   1    h1     m1           sarah@mail
1    bob   2    h2     m2             bob@mail
2  jones   3    h3     m3  jones@mail,joe@mail <- join duplicates
3  jones   4    h4     m4          jones2@mail
```